# Sorting two arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve one of algorithm problem. The problem looks very challenging. But, I think can solved by shorting the arrays...

**Problem Description**

Task. You are given a set of points on a line and a set of segments on a line. The goal is to compute, for each point, the number of segments that contain this point.

**Input Format.** The first line contains two non-negative integers s and p defining the number of segments and the number of points on a line, respectively. The next s lines contain two integers ai, bi defining the i-th segment [ai, bi]. The next line contains p integers defining points x1, x2, . . . , xp.

**Constraints.** 1 ≤ ,  ≤ 50000; −108 ≤  ≤  ≤ 108 for all 0 ≤  < ; −108 ≤  ≤ 108 for all 0 ≤  < .

**Output Format.** Output p non-negative integers k0, k1, . . . , k(p-1) where ki is the number of segments which contain xi.

> Sample 1.
>
> Input:
>
> 2 3
>
> 0 5
>
> 7 10
>
> 1 6 11
>
> Output: `1 0 0`

Here, we have two segments and three points. The first point lies only in the first segment while the
remaining two points are outside of all the given segments.

I want to make one function by using JS that **short** the items of the arrays by comparing first items of arrays and return that shortedArray in **best time complexity**...
How can I do that ?

Example:

```
let segments = [[ [ 1, 'L' ], [ 2, 'R' ] ], [ [ 0, 'L' ], [ 15, 'R' ] ], [ [ 7, 'L' ], [ 10, 'R' ] ] ] ;
let points = [ [ 1, 'P' ], [ 6, 'P' ], [ 11, 'P' ] ] ;
```

newArray should be :

```
shortedArray = [[0,'L'],[1,'L'],[1,'P'],[2,'R'],[6,'P'],[7,'L'],[10,'R'],[11,'P'],[15,'R']] ;
```

I have stucked to remove bracklets from the arrays and make them basic.

Example

I do not have any idea how to convert the **segments** array to that below one

```
segments = [ [ 0, 'L' ], [ 15, 'R' ], [  7, 'L' ], [ 10, 'R' ] ]  ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: it is not sorted yet... I am looking firstly short the first array and then second one and finally merge them. But I have no idea how to remove bracklets from the first array before the sorting. @MrSmith42

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `flat()` and `sort()` to archive this. You have to use flat because your fist array has an other structure as the second.

```js
const segments = [ [ [ 0, 'L' ], [ 15, 'R' ] ], [ [ 7, 'L' ], [ 10, 'R' ] ] ] ;
const points = [ [ 1, 'P' ], [ 6, 'P' ], [ 11, 'P' ] ];

const a = [...segments.flat(),...points].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

console.log(a)
```

`flat()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

`sort()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the arrays using [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) into one single array, then sort this array by it's first value.

```js
const 
  segments = [ [ [ 0, 'L' ], [ 15, 'R' ] ], [ [ 7, 'L' ], [ 10, 'R' ] ] ],
  points = [ [ 1, 'P' ], [ 6, 'P' ], [ 11, 'P' ] ],
  result = [].concat(...segments, points).sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);

console.log(result);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: if `let segments = [[ [ 1, 'L' ], [ 2, 'R' ] ], [ [ 0, 'L' ], [ 15, 'R' ] ], [ [ 7, 'L' ], [ 10, 'R' ] ] ] ;`
`points = [ [ 1, 'P' ], [ 6, 'P' ], [ 11, 'P' ] ],`

expected result should have been  that:  `result = [[0,'L'],[1,'L'],[1,'P'],[2,'R'],[6,'P'],[7,'L'],[10,'R'],[11,'P'],[15,'R']] ;` But your snippets not exactly working as my wish.

Comment: @CihatŞaman What do you want when there's a match, like `[1, 'L']` from `segments` & `[1, 'P']` from `points`? Looks like you want to put items from `segments` before in case of ties. I've updated my answer to handle the same.

Comment: My main purpose is that  just need to count how many (“LEFT” — “RIGHT”) items appeared before “POINT” item. 
Example for the first point there is two item of 'L' before the first point and 1 item 'R' is after the first point so there is just one “LEFT” — “RIGHT” item... I will modify the question with more details...